# ubuntu 20 and i40e

Tags: drivers, intel

We are upgrading some of our older machines from centos6 to ubuntu 18/20. I have a preseed config (that works fine for other machines). However, when installing on this machine with the i40e driver (I built and installed the latest, 2.11.25, I can't get link. Physically, it shows link lights, but the OS doesn't see it.

Interesting that dmesg, though, shows my 10G devices as
7f:0e.2 Unassigned class [ffff]: Intel Corporation Device 6ff2 (rev 01)

Comment: As it turns out, it doesn't work on boot, but if I rmmod and then modprobe after it is up, it works.

Comment: Updated nvm fw, no help. I notice that it reports link when it comes up as eth0, but somehow loses it when it gets renamed to it's new name. For now, I have a systemd service that removes the mod and re-loads it after the machine starts.

Comment: For reference:
[Unit]
Description=Reload i40e driver
After=systemd-modules-load.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/rmmod i40e
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/modprobe i40e

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target